# Error(34,24): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing oracle function and i am getting some compile time error;

```
create or replace FUNCTION GETSUBLOCATIONS 
(
P_LocationID VARCHAR2
)RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
BEGIN
    Declare P_ID varchar2(500):='';
    begin
      INSERT INTO "HIL"."P_TEMP" (DATA)( SELECT PLANT_CODE 
       FROM "HIL"."TBLPLANTMASTER" 
       WHERE    PLANT_MASTER_LOCATION ='P_LocationID');
       DECLARE P_ROWS INT:=0;
        BEGIN
          SELECT COUNT(*)INTO P_ROWS FROM P_TEMP;


    IF(P_ROWS > 0)
    THEN
    DECLARE P_I INT  := 1;  
    BEGIN
    DECLARE P_STR VARCHAR2:='';
    BEGIN
    WHILE(P_I < P_ROWS)
    LOOP
    SELECT "HIL"."P_TEMP".data into P_STR FROM P_TEMP  WHERE ID = P_I;
    P_ID := P_ID + P_STR;
    PI:= PI + 1;
    END LOOP;        
    END;
  END;
                     END IF;
 END;
RETURN P_ID;

END GETSUBLOCATIONS;
```

i am getting following error

> Error(34,24): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when
>   expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception
>   exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update
>   while with     
>    << continue close current delete fetch lock
>   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge
>   pipe purge

Comment: You must be missing a `/` after `END;` statement.

Comment: After end I kept / symbol . but it is also showing some compile time error

Comment: This error always means the code is missing a closing keyword - an `if` is missing its `end if;` a `declare` or `begin` is missing its `end;` or something like that. By the way, I'd like to hear you talk me through your indentation system ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had *properly indented your code* the problem would become obvious:

```
create or replace FUNCTION GETSUBLOCATIONS 
( P_LocationID VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
BEGIN
    Declare P_ID varchar2(500):='';
    begin
        INSERT INTO "HIL"."P_TEMP" (DATA)( SELECT PLANT_CODE 
        FROM "HIL"."TBLPLANTMASTER" 
        WHERE    PLANT_MASTER_LOCATION ='P_LocationID');

        DECLARE P_ROWS INT:=0;
        BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT(*)INTO P_ROWS FROM P_TEMP;
            IF(P_ROWS > 0) THEN
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE P_I INT  := 1;  
                    DECLARE P_STR VARCHAR2:='';
                    BEGIN
                        WHILE(P_I < P_ROWS) LOOP
                            SELECT "HIL"."P_TEMP".data into P_STR FROM P_TEMP  WHERE ID = P_I;
                            P_ID := P_ID + P_STR;
                            PI:= PI + 1;
                        END LOOP;        
                    END;
                END;
            END IF;
        END;
        RETURN P_ID;
    ***MISSING END HERE***
END GETSUBLOCATIONS;
```

You are missing the finishing `END` from the first `BEGIN`.

Comment: Error(16,21): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.

Comment: Error(25,17): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:     ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>

Comment: @sudhakarnayak I put this answer here to show you what the problem is with your code indentation.  There may well be other logical problems with your code itself

Comment: The block beginning `DECLARE P_I INT` is incomplete. Aligning `p_i_int` on its own line would make this clearer.

Comment: thank you, Problem is i was missing the finishing END from the first BEGIN.Thank you @martin

Answer (score 1):

There are too much BEGIN and declare lines in your code. Please reduce your code to -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GETSUBLOCATIONS(
    P_LocationID VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
P_ID VARCHAR2(500):='';
P_ROWS INT:=0;
P_I INT := 1;

BEGIN
    INSERT
    INTO "HIL"."P_TEMP"(DATA)
    SELECT PLANT_CODE
    FROM "HIL"."TBLPLANTMASTER"
    WHERE PLANT_MASTER_LOCATION =P_LocationID;

    SELECT COUNT(*)INTO P_ROWS FROM P_TEMP;
    IF(P_ROWS > 0) THEN
          FOR I IN (SELECT "HIL"."P_TEMP".data 
                    FROM P_TEMP
                    WHERE ID = P_I)       -- You must ommit where clause if you need all the IDs.
          LOOP
              P_ID := P_ID || I.data;
          END LOOP;
    END IF;
    RETURN P_ID;
EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
              NULL;
END GETSUBLOCATIONS;
/
```

Comment: Using `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
              NULL;` is one of the worst things you can do.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, Since I do not know what all exceptions to handle, This is the most generic way to handle exceptions. What other ways would you suggest as a teacher?

Comment: This is the worst generic way to handle exceptions because you silently ignore any kind of error. If you expect specific error then handle it properly. All others unhandled errors should be raised.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I like the refactoring, but I have to agree with Wemfried that unless you specifically want a step to continue after failure the best way to handle unknown exceptions is no exception handler. Then transactions are rolled back, the caller is notified, and the error stack indicates the cause.